# Camera not in Outliner or in 3d view

Tags: camera

My Camera is not visible in the outliner or in the 3D view but if i press num0 i can see its view. But i can't delet it because i cant find it. I can't select it or something else.
Its like it isn't realy there.

I hope you cant finde a solution

Julius

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do not need to have a camera, you can set any object as camera by selecting the object and pressing ctrl + 0, just add a camera, and with the camera selected press ctrl + 0

Answer (score -1):

Add a camera to the scene then press the keystroke.

To add a camera press

<kbd>Shift A</kbd>

Then Select Camera